# Render problems on Android using OpenGL ES 2.0

Tags: android, android-fragments, rendering, opengl-es-2.0, glsurfaceview

I have a problem with some rendering on Android. I spent two days to find a solution and I could not found something relevant. I will be grateful to anyone that can give me a hint.

The situation: I have **one activity** in which I use **two different fragments** . In the **first fragment I use two custom GLSurfaceViews**, each one having a custom Renderer. The gl surface views are displaying some bitmaps. **In the second fragment I use one custom GLSurfaceView** with a custom Renderer. This view renders camera frames.       Note: The navigation between fragments it's done using a switch button(hide/show fragments). For the first time, the first activity is visible, and when the switch button is pressed the second fragment becomes visible)

The problem:

Use case:

The user enters the activity and the two GLSurfaceViews appear to render the bitmaps correctly. When I press the switch button in order to go to the second fragment, this is where problem appears. **The video is rendered** on the GLSurfaceView **but in its top right corner somehow it displays the second image that was rendered in the first Android fragment**. It gives me the impression that the second SurfaceView used in the first fragment is still rendering in the second fragment (in the same position) Note: the two opengl surface views in the first Android fragment are smaller than the one used in the second fragment. **And when I return back to the first fragment, I cannot see the Bitmap rendered in the first GLSurfaceView**, instead I see the last frame of the camera(which was stopped). The second image is rendered correctly(the same image that appeared in the second fragment on top of the camera frames).

If the activity starts with the second fragment, the video frames are displayed correctly and then when I switch to the first fragment the problem appears again.

**I call onPause(), onResume() methods** of the surface views and I **release the textures** and all the buffers and programs when I leave each fragment.

**Is there a way to use multiple GLSurfaceViews with their own renderes in the same Activity without having such problems?**

**Thank you** in advance. If I was not so clear please say so and I'll make a sketch(cannot put screenshots due to legal issues).

Any tip may help, Thank you guys! :)

**EDIT:**

I solved my problem by removing/adding the GLSurfaceViews when navigating between the fragments. In onResume I add my GLSurfaceView to its parent -- parent.addView(mSurface), and in onPause I removed myGLSurfaceView from its parent -- parent.removeView(mSurface).

But ... I still do not know why the first approach does not work. My problem is solved but an explanation will be welcome for others with similar problems.

Comment: There used to be a bug with having multiple `GLSurfaceView` instances, but it's marked as fixed: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2828.

Comment: Yes I saw the report. I forgot to mention it in the question. Thx

Answer (score 1):

Android does not easily support using more than one GLSurfaceView at a time in the same app.  This is because each instance of GLSurfaceView spawns its own execution thread and EGL context and there is little support on Android for making calls to OpenGL ES from multiple threads or contexts.  It may be possible to do this, but you would have to check the EGL context before every OpenGL ES call.  This [article](https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/porting-opengl-games-to-android-on-intel-atom-processors-part-1) explains in more detail.

Comment: Using multiple `GLSurfaceView` instances should be fine. Each one will have it's own context and rendering thread, so they won't get in each others way. Where people run into difficulties is if they try to render into the same view from multiple threads.

Comment: Thank you Clay! This could help me understand better certain things